# How to make DIVs or SPANs to have a fixed width with content plus rest available space with white space?

Tags: html, css, freemarker

I currently have something like the below.

```
<div width="100%">
  <span width="33%">FIRSTNAME</span>
  <span width="33%">|LASTNAME</span>
  <span width="33%">|CITY</span>
</div>
```

Which on execution looks something like below:

```
FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME|CITY
```

But what I actually require is something like below: (Occupies 100% of the page width, where the span elements each are 33% of the main DIV element)

```
FIRSTNAME                      |LASTNAME                       |CITY
```

Please, can anybody suggest a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
div {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: space-between; /* evenly distributed */
}

span {
  flex: 1; /* each 33.33% of the flex-container's (parent's) width */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>FIRSTNAME</span>
  <span>|LASTNAME</span>
  <span>|CITY</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with css

```
<div class="container">
  <span>FIRSTNAME</span>
  <span>|LASTNAME</span>
  <span>|CITY</span>
</div>

body {
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.container span {
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block
}
```

Or you can use bootstrap to help you with this

https://getbootstrap.com/